# Oracle.DataAccess Update Using ExecuteNonQuery does not update

Tags: .net, oracle, updates

This problem is specific to Oracle.DataAccess.  I have no troubles using MSSQL.

I am unable to update an Oracle 12c database row using .NET and Oracle.Access 4.121.2.0.  No problem retrieving data from the same Oracle Database using .NET.  There is no problem updating through SQLDeveloper.

I've cobbled together this Update command from several web sources.   It encounters no error but the update just does not commit or it can't find the record to update.  What am I doing wrong?

Sorry to bother you all but I am stuck and at a time crunch.
Thank you.

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Using connection As New OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LearnConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        connection.Open()

        Dim command As OracleCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
        Dim numberOfUpdatedRecords As Integer = 0

        command.CommandText = "UPDATE USERS SET BATCH_UID = :NEW_VALUE WHERE BATCH_UID = :OLD_VALUE"

        With command.Parameters
            .Clear()
            .Add(":OLD_VALUE", "name_bbadmin")
            .Add(":NEW_VALUE", "name_library")
        End With
        Try
            numberOfUpdatedRecords = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("No Errors: {0} is return value.", numberOfUpdatedRecords))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ERROR: {0}", ex.Message))
        End Try
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways that parameters can be bound in an OracleCommand.

By default, the command.BindByName value is false, so the name of the parameter is ignored and they are used in the order they have been added in the parameters list.

If you set BindByName to true it will use the parameter name when binding the variables. This will give you the behavior you were expecting.

http://www.oracle.com/au/products/database/o55odpnet-101704.html

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer in the hope that others might benefit.
The following code does work. The primary (and telling) difference is the parameter usage on the Oracle command creation.  Unfortunately, I don't know quite enough to explain why they are necessary.  Perhaps someone more skilled can comment?

Thank you.

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
 Using connection As New OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LearnConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        connection.Open()

        Dim command As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand(String.Empty, connection) _
                                               With {.CommandType = CommandType.Text, .BindByName = True}

        command.CommandText = "UPDATE USERS SET BATCH_UID = :OLD_VALUE WHERE BATCH_UID = :NEW_VALUE"
        Dim numberOfUpdatedRecords As Integer = 0

        With command.Parameters
            .Add(":OLD_VALUE", "name_bbadmin")
            .Add(":NEW_VALUE", "name_library")
        End With
        Try
            numberOfUpdatedRecords = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("No Errors: {0} is return value.", numberOfUpdatedRecords))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ERROR: {0}", ex.Message))
        End Try
    End Using
```